# Payment Method not showing information in admin order detail

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3

I've created a custom payment method and want to see the information inside the admin order detail page.

The payment method is a custom instore payment method and working so far.

I'd like to know how to get the name of the used payment method or its additional information into the order detail page
[image]

I already tried to follow the instructions from the  [official magento 2.3 docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/base-integration/module-configuration.html) . <del>The examples are not working and containing deprecated functions.</del>

The examples in the docs for the braintree module are not working for my use-case and some functions used for the offline-payments are deprecated: e.g [bank transfer payment model](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/f4c1d7526f05bdfb1327b0701cc345f94aadcaed/app/code/Magento/OfflinePayments/Model/Banktransfer.php#L55) using `$this->getConfigData(..)` from `Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` indicates a deprection `@deprecated 100.0.6` for the file. The function `getConfigData()` is deprecated in `@deprecated 100.2.0`

Unfortunately it doesn't give any clue how to replace the deprecated function and only points to the devdocs in version 2.1.

Since this payment method is offline I also tried to make my codes similar to the [offline payment methods on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3/app/code/Magento/OfflinePayments).

Comment: Use can use `aditionalInformation` property of payment entity to store all custom details, also you need to specify `paymentInfoKeys` and `privateInfoKeys` in the payment `config.xml`. What examples are not working from the documentation?

Comment: Sounds good, can you supply with an example for a `config.xml` using these types of information?

Comment: As an example, you can look into Braintree, Cybersource, eWay, Worldpay integrations. `Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` is deprecated and should not be used. The official documentation describes only recommended approach based on Payment Gateway - this approach applicable for offline and online payment solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem.

In my paymentmethod I needed to create/update the file in the

`namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Info`

file as follows:

```
use Magento\Payment\Block\ConfigurableInfo;

class LocalPayment extends ConfigurableInfo
{
    protected function getLabel($field)
    {
        return __($field);
    }
}
```

This will render the paymentMethod name into the orders. It will also do this for past created orders.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can you share how you implemented the new offline method?

Comment: I found a open-source payment-method and adopted it for my needs. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code any more